# Deserializing the contents of a listview

Tags: c#, wpf, deserialization

I have a ListView which contains ListViewItems. I have the following code to serialize my list view, at the moment this just creates a file with the xaml.

```
private void SerializeToXML()
{
    FileStream filestream = File.Create(@"H:\test1.xaml");
    StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream);

    foreach (ListViewItem Item in slideListView.Items)
    {
        string mystrXAMLWrite = XamlWriter.Save(Item.Tag);
        streamwriter.Write(mystrXAMLWrite);
    }

    streamwriter.Close();
    filestream.Close();
}
```

What I'm having problems with is going about de serializing the contents of this file into a ListView.

Can anyone explain how I would do this?

So far for a deserialize method I have:

```
private void DeSerialize()
{
    FileStream filestream = File.Open(@"H:\test1.xaml", FileMode.Open);

    XamlReader reader = new XamlReader();
    reader.LoadAsync(filestream);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`XamlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) class, to load the Xaml from the file and then set the contents of the ListView to it.

Although, this looks like a dead end, so it may be better to serialize the data (ItemsSource) you are using to populate the ListView in the first place. i.e. ViewModel / Model if using the MVVM pattern.

### MVVM Pattern (Model View ViewModel)

Because of the binding engine that WPF uses, it is quite useful to use the MVVM pattern in combination with WPF.
It also seperates the Display logic from the business and data logic, A **View** can know about a **ViewModel**, but the **ViewModel** doesn't know about the **View** and shouldn't have logic that dictates what the **View** will look like. You could also use a dependency injection framework such as MEF to further decouple between the components and aid with Unit Testing.

The **Model** contains a mixture of data access and state, so you could serialize and deserialize the Model when it comes to saving and loading the ListView items.

The **ViewModel** is an abstraction of the **View**. Your application may only have one Model but plenty of Views that are related to it. So the **ViewModel** would contain any relevant properties you want from the **Model** to interact with in a current **View**

Finally the **View** displays the **ViewModel**.

So what would this mean code wise?

We end up with two classes and a xaml Window/Page/User Control.

I'll provide some interfaces as a guide.

```
public interface IMyData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  Properties...
}

public interface IMyModel
{
   IList<IMyData> Items { get; set; }

   void Serialize(string filePath);

   void Deserialize(string filePath);
}

public interface IMyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   IMyModel Model { get; set; }

   ObservableCollection<IMyData> Items { get; set; }

   ICommand Save { get; }

   ICommand Load { get; }

   ICommand Add { get; }

   ICommand Remove { get; }
}
```

The **View** can be done entirely in Xaml, this is useful if you are working on a team with a UI Designer as they can be working on the look and feel without upsetting your work too much in the **ViewModel** and **Model**

**Xaml** uses `DataTemplates` to describe how UI elements should display their `DataContext`.

In the **View** we can add the **ViewModel** as a resource.

```
<Window xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp.MyViewModels">
   <Window.Resources>
      <vm:MyViewModelImplementation x:Key="ViewModel" />
   </Window.Resources>
...
```

Then we can set the lowest UI elements DataContext to be the ViewModel, for instance you may wish to use a grid as the base ui element.

```
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}">
   ...
</Grid>
```

Now when we display the `ListView` of items the `ListView` will look something like this.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
   <ListView.ItemsTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}" />
         </StackPanel>
      <DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemsTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Say you want to be able to add new items to your collection by pressing a `Button`.

The Xaml markup would look like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Add}">Add</Button>
```

and the Command property in the **ViewModel** would be this.

```
public MyViewModelImplementation()
{
   Add = new RelayCommand(AddItem);
}

private void AddItem()
{
   DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
   {
      Items.Add(new MyData());
   });
}
```

Since we are using an `ObservableCollection<T>` the UI will be updated, but you need to invoke the UI thread since it has to be Modified on the thread it was created from.

[MVVM Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)
[MVVMLight](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com)

Comment: I have added some code to my original post but gow would i go about setting the contents to the listview.

Comment: I don't understand your second point, can you elaborate.. The ListView I have is populated with ListViewItems at runtime by a user the ListViewItems consist of Content and a Tag. The Content is some Text and an Image, but the Tag is a custom UserControl. I don't really know anything about MVVM but would that work in this situation?

Comment: WPF Applications are usually created using the Model View ViewModel pattern, it is made easier if you use an existing frame work such as MVVMLight. I'll update my answer with a sample.