# Creating a custom image class in WPF following MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Im just starting out with MVVM and at the moment still find alot of things confusing.

So I am trying to keep things as simple as I can at the moment.

I am trying to write code for a custom image which later will be able to be placed on a canvas control by a user at runtime. I'm trying to use MVVM so that I will be able to save and reload the content on a canvas.

I have created a model class called CustomImage with the following code:

```
namespace StoryboardToolMvvm
{
    public class CustomImage
    {
        public Uri imageLocation { get; set; }
        public BitmapImage bitmapImage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have a modelview class as follows:

```
namespace StoryboardToolMvvm
{
    class CustomImageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private CustomImage _customImage;
        private ObservableCollection<CustomImage> _customImages;
        private ICommand _SubmitCommand; 

        public CustomImage CustomImage
        {
            get { return _customImage; }

            set
            {
                _customImage = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CustomImage");
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<CustomImage> CustomImages
        {
            get { return _customImages; }

            set
            {
                _customImages = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("CustomImages");
            }
        }

        public ICommand SubmitCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_SubmitCommand == null)
                {
                    _SubmitCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.Submit(), null);
                }
                return _SubmitCommand;
            }
        }

        public CustomImageViewModel()
        {
            CustomImage = new CustomImage();
            CustomImages = new ObservableCollection<CustomImage>();
            CustomImages.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(CustomImages_CollectionChanged);
        }

        private void CustomImages_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CustomImages");
        }

        private void Submit()
        {
            CustomImage.imageLocation = new Uri(@"H:\My Pictures\whale.png");
            CustomImage.bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(CustomImage.imageLocation);
            CustomImages.Add(CustomImage);
            CustomImage = new CustomImage();
        }

    }
}
```

And a view class:

```
<UserControl x:Class="StoryboardToolMvvm.CustomImageView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:StoryboardToolMvvm"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <viewmodel:CustomImageViewModel x:Key="CustomImageViewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource CustomImageViewModel}}">
            <Image Source="{Binding CustomImage.bitmapImage, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="150" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="75,50,0,0" />
            <Button Content="Submit" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}" Width="100" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,20" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I add this view to my MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StoryboardToolMvvm" x:Class="StoryboardToolMvvm.MainWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>

        <local:CustomImageView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="181,110,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I am very unsure as to whether I am on the right lines here with a MVVM pattern so any comments would be much appreciated. Also when Submit is pressed I would have expected my image to load but this does not happen can anyone advise as to why?

Many Thanks in advance..

Comment: Why do you expect that the image would load? You are creating a CustomImage right after the image load so it updates the binding. But there is another problem: CustomImage is not implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and it does not notifies the observers about bitmapImage changes.

Comment: Please tell me your exact problem and what you want to achieve because this is not clear from your question.

Comment: Hi, I have an wpf app which I am trying to convert to MVVM because I was having problems trying to serialize and deserialize my old program so that I could save and load. I was advised that MVVM is the way to go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856474/wpf-deserializing-the-contents-of-a-listview/17856717?noredirect=1#comment26073106_17856717 So right now im just trying to get my head around the basics of MVVM and with the code in this post I am just trying to create a customControl which will display an image, eventually I will attach event handlers to the image to perform move, resize etc

Comment: Remove the last line that instantiates customImage  in submit function and then verify properties that need be refreshed all implement INotifyPropertyChanged. And then consider output box for any binding errors

Comment: Hi HichemCSharp, I have removed the line that instantiates customImage, I have added code to my view model to implement NotifyPropertyChange on Uri and BitmapImage, a get and set which does the same as the other get and sets in my view model. But this hasnt solved anything. Can you see where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As far as my understanding of MVVM and your question goes, I have one main comment about your code.
I think your CustomImage is actually both Model and ViewModel layer, and you should split it in two :

- the Model, which would contain the path itself ;
- the ViewModel, which contain the BitmapImage and initialize it from the Model and constructing time.

The path is the mere data used for saving, and it fits the Model, whereas the BitmapImage is how the data is shown and should be constructed in the ViewModel.

One advantage is that now, your BitmapImage gets its own NotifyPropertyChanged call at setting time, and you won't have anymore problem or a View part directly bound to the Model.

As for your CustomImageViewModel, this looks like more of a MainViewModel-ish thing. You can still use this to store the ViewModels.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.